# JQuery plugin files don't work in my Django Template

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins, django-templates

I am trying to load JQuery plugins in a django template html file, but there is some issue that prevents the loaded file to work. I'm new to JS / JQuery so maybe I am missing a simple point.

Here is what I have entered before the < / body> tag, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}project/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}project/js/jquery.freezeheader.js"></script>
<script> <!-- script for fixed table head -->   
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#fixedh").freezeHeader({ 'height': '300px' });
        })
</script>
```

The only way to make it work it to insert the actual code as a script inside my local file.

Is there any way to make the external .js load properly? 
I am using Django 1.6

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Can you check if the files are being loaded in the browser? Maybe you're not setting the static file settings correctly.

Comment: Static file settings seem correct, as the files are being loaded into the browser. And the main jquery file (jquery-1.11.3.js) is also located in my static folder and it seems to work properly.